# Best way to empty a multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have several processes receiving packets and dumping them into a common queue.
The main process checks up on the queue once per second, grabbing all available packets and processing them.

What is the safest way to pull all items out of a queue? I've tried several methods and they all seem to have problems.

**Method 1 - Non-blocking Gets**

```
packets = []
while True:
    try:
        packets.append(queue.get(block=False))
    except Queue.Empty:
        break
```

Method 1 has a problem where `queue.get(block=False)` seems to raise `Queue.Error` even when there are still packets left in the queue. I think this happens if it fails to immediately acquire a lock. The end effect is that the queue is only partially emptied while `queue.qsize()` shows many more waiting in the queue. The number of packets in the queue continues to grow as the program runs, and the processing lags behind. I can work around the issue by emptying the queue more 4-5 times a second but I don't control the rate at which packets come in so I'm not sure this is a permanent solution.

**Method 2 - Blocking Gets**

```
packets = []
while True:
    try:
        packets.append(queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.01))
    except Queue.Empty:
        break
```

Method 2 fixes the growing queue issue but has another problem where emptying the queue takes a relatively long time. I'm also concerned that this loop might never exit if the contributing processes are always dumping packets into the queue before the timeout can expire.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

could you do something like

```
packets = []
while failures < 3:
    try:
        packets.append(queue.get(block=False))
        failures = 0
    except Queue.Empty:
        failures += 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

or better yet probably

```
while not queue.empty():
    try:
        packets.append(queue.get(block=False))
    except Queue.Empty:
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The failures counter doesn't work, at least not with the values 3 - 30. I don't think the queue has a poll() method.

Comment: oops ... too many things ... try the version there now ...are you sure the queue has stuff left in it when the Queue.Empty exception is fired? how are you sure?

Comment: The queue.empty() version seems to have fixed it when running under Windows but under Linux it still builds up packets. I'm checking qsize() after each loop and it keeps increasing. It eventually fills up with thousands of packets. Only happens under high packet load.

Comment: The next logical step is trying: while queue.qsize(): which fixes the issue. But it takes approximately the same amount of time as Method 2. In both of these I'd be concerned the loop would never exit if the processes keep stuffing packets into the queue fast enough.

Comment: why not just do the `while not queue.empty` which if there is a couple left ... just call it every few seconds and get those other messages on the next call